# Attic access, feasibility-how-to question

Tags: pipe, attic, vent, joists, carpentry

We are trying to build an attic access to our second story. The plan was by to support and cut the middle joist (pic), and box it out. The hole in the drywall is into a closet. We were going to remove a wall in the closet to install a ship ladder, and re-frame the closet wall at an angle under it.
I believe the pipe may be a dwv pipe. Is there any how-to for moving these? Any other suggestions or problems we may face? Thank you!

[image]

Edit: I am 80% sure it is a drain vent pipe. I know joists hold things up, but from my understanding it is standard to cut one and box out the opening for attic access. Unless someone has other ideas

Comment: First of all I dont think you dhould be cutting the joist. They tend to hold up things. You may need to remove a few more boards to get a better overview. You need to be sure what the pipe is. Did you mesn DWV?

Comment: Is that pipe metal or plastic? Does a magnet stick to it? It might be a gas pipe, if the house has gas service, and that would be ...not good to get wrong. I guess the writing I can sort of make out implies more likely black plastic  ABS DWV pipe.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [register](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting responses as answers can result in an automated lock that would prevent others from assisting you.

Answer (score 1):

A DWV pipe under an attic floor would almost certainly be a dry vent pipe, there are very few restrictions on what you can do with those, as long as they do not have reverse slope. It will still have to meet up with some vent pipe going thru the roof. Any hardware store will have the necessary fittings, ABS cement, and short lengths of pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Often when you cut a joist and install headers, you need to add "sister" joists to reinforce the existing joists to either side of the cut joist. If the remaining chunks of the removed joist are both 3 ft long or shorter, then you can install a header without these "sisters." See [IRC R502.10](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.10).

If the remaining chunks of joist do not satisfy the 3 ft rule, then see [How Do I Frame an Opening in My Bathroom Floor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284179/how-do-i-frame-an-opening-in-my-bathroom-floor/284181).

Answer (score 0):

An ABS pipe in the attic is a vent pipe if there's nothing draining in your attic. I'll assume that's what you have. The [International Plumbing Code's 905.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-9-vents#IPC2021P1_Ch09_Sec905.2) requires that

> Vent and branch vent pipes shall be so graded and connected as to drain back to the drainage pipe by gravity.

There's a chance that rain water or backed up drain water will enter these pipes, so gravity drainage guarantees that such water finds its way to the sewer. And that's it. Any 90 degree bends are okay as long as the maze drains by gravity.

If you want to punch through floor joists with this pipe, however, there's constraints on the hole sizes and locations. [IRC R502.8.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.8.1) requires that the holes have diameter no greater than 1/3 the joist's depth and that the holes leave the joist's top 2" and bottom 2" uncut. There are commercially available hole reinforcing systems if you need to cut larger holes or to encroach on the top 2" or bottom 2".