# How Do I Frame an Opening in My Bathroom Floor

Tags: bathroom, drain, structural, joists, support

I am fixing termite eaten and improperly spaced joists in my home. I need to create space for the bathtub drain fixtures, which are currently riding right up on a joist that runs under the bathtub, leaving no room for sistering the joist. If I sister the joists on both sides, how big can the opening be so that I can use it for the bathtub, toilet, and sink drains? It's a small bathroom. See p. 11 from HUD's [The Rehab Guide Volume 5: Partitions, Ceilings, Floors, and Stairs](https://www.huduser.gov/publications/pdf/part.pdf):

[image: Floor opening]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use single headers (same size as the joists) for spans up to 4 feet long. Doubled trimmers (the original joists plus a sister each) are necessary instead of single trimmers unless you meet an unusual exception from the International Residential Code (IRC) that's barely worth mentioning. The distance between headers across the opening is unconstrained. See [IRC R502.10](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.10) for the official version.

For headers any longer than 4 feet, the doubled trimmers are no longer adequate. The original unsistered joists both carry a 16" wide band (wall-to-wall) of floor load; that's an 8" wide band on the header side of both joists. Both sistering joists each add another 16" of floor load carrying capacity. These contributions add up to an 8" + 16" + 16" + 8" = 48" = 4'-0" wide band of floor load carrying capacity. This is why the doubled trimmers max out with 4 feet wide headers. If you want headers longer than 4 feet, then you'll need additional trimmers. How many trimmers? The 8"+16"+16"+8" procedure from above generalizes, where it must have the same number of trimmers on both sides. (Confirm that you understand by computing the max header width for 6 total trimmers as 6'-8".)

If you want headers longer than 4 feet, then you'll also need at least doubled headers. You can get header sizes from [IRC Table R602.7(2)](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7_TblR602.7_2) (header spans for interior bearing walls supporting one floor only), where the table's "building width" is the length of the tail joists (the joists that dead-end into the header).

*Barely Worth Mentioning*:

If the tail joist/joists is/are 3 feet long or shorter and if the corresponding header is 4 feet long or shorter, then single trimmers are sufficient.

Comment: I need a 6 feet in length gap (4 ft width is fine, no need for more)  to have pipe access for the entire bathroom, but does that leave too large of an area unsupported, or does the double trimmers cover for it? Could I go even further and have no headers and no severed joist at all, just remove the joist entirely and double or triple the trimmers? Or would I need headers every X feet in place of a joist? (oh and 8+16+16+16+16+8=80)

Comment: @Zen00, your header is 4'-0" or shorter, right? The opening size perpendicular to the headers can be any length, but the key word is "opening." You're eliminating support from below the floor sheathing, so the area above the _opening_ is no longer intended as a walking surface. If you intend to walk and/or apply loads between holes drilled in the floor sheathing over the framed opening, you can install new framing in the opening to support these walking/loaded areas. Without such framing, your floor will be under strength and squishy.

Comment: @Zen00, when this new framing runs parallel to the headers, I would space it every 12". When this new framing runs parallel to the trimmers, I would space it the same as the floor joists are spaced.