# Making a secret passage to my attic. Can I cut the ceiling joists?

Tags: ceiling, attic, joists

I am putting a secret passage in my linen closet behind a grandfather clock (a la the Webster show) to access my attic.  My question is:  Can I cut the ceiling joists to make the opening bigger?

Here are pics of the project.

This is the linen closet:

[image]

This door above is currently the only way to access the attic space.

[image]

This is the hole I made in the ceiling of the linen closet.  Can I cut the wood on each side of the hole to make it bigger?

[image]

This is the interior of the linen closet.

[image]

This is the ladder I bought to put inside.

[image]

This is the grandfather clock I got for free (almost not worth it with how bad it smelled like cigarettes) that I’m going to mount on the door with z clips.

[image]

Here is my attic.  The hole will be about three feet in towards the left side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about a picture of the actual framing from above or at least a sketch of the framing with a rectangular box marking the perimeter of the hole that you want. The details without an engineer come from [IRC R502.10](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.10). See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284179/how-do-i-frame-an-opening-in-my-bathroom-floor/ for an explanation.